# Why am I getting a Nonetype when I try to scrape data from webpages?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from the table in the following link:

https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1010014101

But, I keep getting NoneType when I try to scrape the data.

Here is the code that I have tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page=requests.get('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1010014101')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html5lib')
x=soup.find('main',role='main')
print(x)
```

I would love to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

requests.get() may be filtered out by the site based on your lack of user-agent. Have you tried using selenium?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/tv.action?pid=1010014101"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")


data = []
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'pub-table'})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

print(data)
```

Once I downloaded the [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and unzipped it into the same directory as my script, this code printed the following for me:

```
[[], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '85,120'], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '49,637'], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '24,056'], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '0'], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '8,462'], ['..', '..', '..', '..', '2,965']]
```